# array of objects entering information

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function add() {
  var students = [{
    name: document.getElementById('nam').value,
    id: document.getElementById('ied').value,
    grade: document.getElementById('gr').value,
  }]
  document.ARR.Name.value = " ";
  document.getElementById("gr").value = " ";
  document.getElementById("ied").value = " ";


  i = i + 1;
  if (i == 5) {
    alert("Max capacity reached")
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" id="nam" /></br>
  </br>
  Grade:<input type="text" name "Mark" id="gr" /> </br>
  </br>
  ID: <input type="text" name "ID" id="ied" /> </br>
  </br>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()" />
</body>

</html>
```

hi guys , im trying to get information from a form and put them in an array of objects . this code isnt working

Comment: You array is filled just fine. It just crashes on the line after it.

Comment: What is `document.ARR` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to use `document.ARR.Name` as a reference to your first input field, but it's not. Simply select it via `getElementById`.

```js
function add() {
  var students = [{
    name: document.getElementById('nam').value,
    id: document.getElementById('ied').value,
    grade: document.getElementById('gr').value,
  }];

  document.getElementById('nam').value = " ";
  document.getElementById("gr").value = " ";
  document.getElementById("ied").value = " ";


  /**i = i + 1;
  if (i == 5) {
    alert("Max capacity reached")
  }*/ // I'm not sure what this is supposed to do, so I simply wrapped it in a comment, since it throws an error
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" id="nam" /></br>
  </br>
  Grade:<input type="text" name "Mark" id="gr" /> </br>
  </br>
  ID: <input type="text" name "ID" id="ied" /> </br>
  </br>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()" />
</body>

</html>
```